# Convert IList to SomeType[]

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, runtime

I have a collection of type List that I want to convert to SomeType[]. SomeType is not known before runtime.

This must be done with the signature of the following procedure.

```
private object ConvertListToArray(IList  collection)
{
       // This does not work since SomeType is not known before runtime.
       var convertedList = collection.Cast<SomeType>().ToArray();
        return convertedList;
}
```

Notice that collection is IList, but it is known that the concrete type is

```
     List<SomeType>
```

The return collection must be an object of type SomeType[].

How can this be done?

Comment: What about collection.ToArray(); Wouldn't this make the trick here?

Comment: How would you *expect* the code to work out that it wanted `SomeType[]` instead of `object[]`, `String[]` or `SomeOtherType[]`? What would you expect if the collection contained a `SomeType` and ` SeomOtherType`? What if it were empty?

Comment: Katalonis - ToArray() is an extension to List<T>, but I have IList.

Comment: Jon Skeet - The concrete list is a generic list, and there is only one type. However when converting I only have IList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T[] ConvertToArray<T>(IList list)
    {
        return list.Cast<T>().ToArray();
    }

    public static object[] ConvertToArrayRuntime(IList list, Type elementType)
    {
        var convertMethod = typeof(ListExtensions).GetMethod("ConvertToArray", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new [] { typeof(IList)}, null);
        var genericMethod = convertMethod.MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
        return (object[])genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {list});
    }

}
[TestFixture]
public class ExtensionTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestThing()
    {
        IList list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("hello");
        list.Add("world");

        var myArray = ListExtensions.ConvertToArrayRuntime(list, typeof (string));
        Assert.IsTrue(myArray is string[]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works very well. To use it with any list, I used
var myArray = ListExtensions.ConvertToArrayRuntime(list, list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);

Comment: I would like to upvote, but my reputation is below 15 so I cannot vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the implementation below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // same type
        var myCollection = new List<string> {"Hello", "World"};
        var array = (string[])myCollection.ConvertToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(array[0]);

        // new type
        var intList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
        var stringArray = (string[])intList.ConvertToArray(typeof(string));
        Console.WriteLine(stringArray[0]);

        // mixed types
        var ouch = new List<object> {1, "Mamma", 3.0};
        var result= (string[])ouch.ConvertToArray(typeof(string));
        Console.WriteLine(result[0]);


    }
}
```

The implementation:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static object ConvertToArray(this IList collection)
    {
        // guess type
        Type type;
        if (collection.GetType().IsGenericType && collection.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Length == 0)
            type = collection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        else if (collection.Count > 0)
            type = collection[0].GetType();
        else
            throw new NotSupportedException("Failed to identify collection type for: " + collection.GetType());

        var array = (object[])Array.CreateInstance(type, collection.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
            array[i] = collection[i];
        return array;
    }

    public static object ConvertToArray(this IList collection, Type arrayType)
    {
        var array = (object[])Array.CreateInstance(arrayType, collection.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
        {
            var obj = collection[i];

            // if it's not castable, try to convert it
            if (!arrayType.IsInstanceOfType(obj))
                obj = Convert.ChangeType(obj, arrayType);

            array[i] = obj;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he said that `SomeType` is not known at compile time.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: I've also updated the example with more dynamic code.

Comment: Thank you very much that works very well. To make it more generic, I used the following:

var array1 = list.ConvertToArray(list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);

Comment: I would like to upvote, but my reputation is below 15 so I cannot vote.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
   private T[] ConvertListToArray<T>(IList collection)
   {
   // This does not work since SomeType is not known before runtime.
            var convertedList = collection.Cast<T>().ToArray();
            return convertedList;
        }
```

Comment: The problem is I do not have T at runtime.

Comment: I don't get your problem. If at runtime you stil haven't got the type I guess this is unsolvable. But looking at the solution I see the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as the other answers seem a bit verbose. I'm pretty sure this does what the OP is looking for. It worked for me.

```
public static Array ConvertToArray(ICollection collection, Type type)
{ 
    var array = Array.CreateInstance(type, collection.Count);

    collection.CopyTo(array, 0);

    return array;
}
```